# Install node_modules to vendor

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

How can I install npm modules locally for each project to `vendor/node_modules` and make `package.json` file see them.

**I don't want to move package.json to vendor folder**

I have bower and in `.bowerrc` I specify the `bower_components` path - that is super easy.

How can I do that with npm ?

I`ve read the docs, npmrc docs, some questions here, googled, wasted more than an hour - still no luck. This is ridiculously hard for such an easy task.

I don't care about minuses, just tell me how to do that finally.

Answer (score 10):

Frustrated by the fact that there seems to be no built in way to install into a `node_modules` folder in an arbitrary subfolder, I came up with a sneaky solution using the two following scripts:

**preinstall.js**

```
var fs = require("fs");
try
{
    fs.mkdirSync("./app/node_modules/");
}
catch(e)
{
}

try
{
    if(process.platform.indexOf("win32") !== -1)
    {
        fs.symlinkSync("./app/node_modules/","./node_modules/","junction");
    }
    else
    {
        fs.symlinkSync("./app/node_modules/","./node_modules","dir");
    }
}
catch(e){}
```

**postinstall.js**

```
var fs = require("fs");
try
{
    if(process.platform.indexOf("win32") !== -1)
    {
        fs.unlinkSync("./node_modules/");
    }
    else
    {
        fs.unlinkSync("./node_modules");
    }
}
catch(e){}
```

All you need to do is use them in your `package.json` file by adding them to the `scripts` option:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node preinstall.js",
    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js"
},
```

So, the big question is: what does it do?

1. Well, when you call `npm install` the `preinstall.js` script fires which creates a `node_modules` in the subfolder you want. Then it creates a `symlink` or (`shortcut` in Windows) from the `node_modules` that `npm` expects to the real `node_modules`.
2. Then `npm` installs all the dependencies.
3. Finally, once all the dependencies are installed, the `postinstall.js` script fires which removes the `symlink`!

Here's a handy [gist](https://gist.github.com/HaykoKoryun/cdfb96894dee766381ed) with all that you need.

Comment: You just saved my day with the symlink idea, that works great with my use case (using the same modules in many projects so hard linking the whole node_modules directory works like a charm).

Comment: This works great for node_modules, but now my gulpfile.js complains there is no local gulp installed unless I keep the symlink by not running postinstall.js
Is there anyway to get gulpfile.js to execute in this scenario?

Comment: @BradBamford, you can modify the `postinstall` script to call `gulp` with [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) before removing the symlink.

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot, not using built-in npm functionality.**

[This discussion](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3597) on the npm github repository covers the issue. It's also being addressed in [this answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706052058/https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#node-modules-is-the-name-of-my-deity-s-arch-rival-and-a-forbidden-word-in-my-religion-can-i-configure-npm-to-use-a-different-folder) which is part of their FAQ.

You can still do the installs "manually" by copying modules into your `/vendor` directory and then calling them using the `require("./vendor/whatever")` syntax...but that means each `require` needs to use your new custom location.  There are a few ways you could handle this but they all mean you are doing extra work in your source to accomodate the custom location.

Comment: **You cannot.**

`npm` uses node's algorithm for finding packages, detailed here: <http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders>

You would have to modify your `node` binary in order to support "vendor/node_modules"

Comment: That's true, but npm won't install to a custom directory either. You can provide a path to require that will be used before node walks the various node_modules locations....but npm still won't install anyplace but node_modules. So you could technically write a node project without using npm but you'd have to hard code every path for every require.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `.tgz` file out of library that you want to vendor.

```bash
git clone git@github.com/foo/library.git
cd library
npm install && npm run build
npm pack <build-dir>
```

Then you copy the `.tgz` file to your project and install it.

```bash
cp library-1-0-0.tgz /path/to/your/project/vendor/
cd /path/to/your/project
npm install ./vendor/library-1-0-0.tgz
```

```json
{
    "name": "your-project",
    "dependencies": {
        "library": "file:vendor/library-1-0-0.tgz"
    } 
}
```

If your library is public update `package.json`, see [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bundledependencies).

```json
"bundledDependencies": [
    "library"
]
```