# yarn - install dependencies for a package in a different folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I would like to install the dependencies for some_project. I know I could `cd` into some_project and then run `yarn install`

But I was wondering if it's possible without changing the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1684) with `yarn` that prevents the `--modules-folder` option from working as intended, however I personally don't like the fact that the option has to be provided in the command line; how would you make sure that on future installs they get installed to your chosen folder?

That's why I came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764704/install-node-modules-to-vendor/30120164#30120164) sneaky solution for `npm` since I wanted full control of the install path, not just into a prefixed version of `node_modules`. It will work just as well with `yarn`, in fact we use it in production and we haven't had a problem yet (fingers crossed).

In a nutshell, you need to `symlink` `node_modules` to your desired folder in the `preinstall` event (to trick `npm` or `yarn`) and then delete the `symlink` in the `postinstall` event.

There's one caveats however, which I didn't mention in the linked answer (since I didn't think of it at the time) and that is, things might not go as planned if the install goes horribly wrong; you'll end up with the `symlink` in place since the `postinstall` event *might* not have been triggered, and then the next install *might* fail since the `symlink` already exists.